# Having 2 tables or 1 larger table MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design, optimization

I read a lot of different things on the Internet about optimizing MySQL.

I have a table about friends. And I distinct 2 kinds of friends : The professional and the "social" (not professional) friends.

My question is :

Let's say I have over 10 millions rows (5 millions professional and 5 millions social) of friends.
Is it better to have them all in a table with 3 columns

-idFriend1, -idFriend2, -isProfessional

Or is it better to have 2 tables (professional and non-professional friends) with only 2 columns (and only half the number of rows) ?

By the way, I will have to do some joining on this table so which is best with and without joining process ?

Comment: I would like to retrieve the list of professional friends for an id (and on the other hand the list of non professional friends for an id). Then I have to join them to the table with the user's detail (name, email, etc).
I won't do any update on it, just insert and delete.

Comment: To what do `idFriend1` and `idFriend2` refer? How are they related to each other?  And can the same person ("friend") be both "professional" and "social"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The evaluation of "best" depends on how you use these entities in the rest of your model, and what kind of queries you'd like to write.

If professional and social friends are really the same (other than their professional or social status), then I'd make just one table.  If it turns out that professional friends have some different attributes -- like job title, worked with at, company name -- distinct from social friends (which might have things like favorite drink, favorite sport, and so on) you might find that two different subset tables are in order.

You might find, in fact, that three tables are in order: a friends table which lists the FriendID and all the common attributes (name, age, address); a professional friends table (which lists professional attributes for a FriendID); and a social friends table (which lists social attributes for a FriendID). This way, you have a super set for validation as an entity with all the common attributes, plus subset tables. You can also then decide if a friend could be both a social and a professional friend at the same time, with that flexibility.

As it stands, though, "best" is a tall order since we don't know anything about how you plan to utilize the tables or how they will relate to the rest of your data model.

Comment: Prof & Soc Friend are a same "entity" (they are from the same table "Users"). The only thing I want to do with the tables Prof & Soc Friends is to list in 2 different html tables the list of professional friends and the list of social friends. (And some times to only show on some pages only the list of professional (or social) friends). The only interaction : I can add or remove a prof/social friend. And in my db, I will only join these tables to the user table to get all the info on the users.

Answer (score 1):

I think I misunderstood your question, and that you care about both who the friends are and need to define the web of relationships between them. In that case I would put the friend info into one table, including their name etc. and have another table with a link between them.

```
CREATE TABLE FRIEND (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO FRIEND (name)
VALUES 
('Andrew')
('John')
('Sally')

CREATE TABLE RELATIONSHIP (
  relationshipId int auto_increment primary key,
  friendId1 int,
  friendId2 int,
  isProfessional boolean
);

INSERT INTO RELATIONSHIP (friendId1, friendId2, isProfessional)
VALUES
(1, 2, TRUE),
(1, 3, FALSE);
```

Friendship is reciprocal, so when searching for friends of a specific person you need to look for their id in both friend 1 and friend 2 and do a union query.

Otherwise enter all relationships into the table both ways which doubles your size of the table but avoids the union which in my experience is slow.

Comment: I've had another thought. What if you move the isProfessional to the relationship table. This allows Andrew to be a professional friend of John but a social friend of Sally